# NSArray and bool values

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, nsarray, boolean

Can an NSArray hold an array of bool values?

The following code runs

```
BOOL b = NO;
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:b]];

NSLog(@"value is %d", [array objectAtIndex:0] );
```

However, I don't get a value of 0 for NO as expected. Instead, this is what I get

> value is 37736096

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, just wrap the booleans in NSNumber:

```
BOOL b = YES;

[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:b]];
```

If you want to retrieve the boolean values, use this:

```
BOOL b = [[array objectAtIndex:i] boolValue]; 
// only if you know for sure it contains a boolean
```

Comment: Can you explain why bool NO becomes a big number? Is that a random value? Thanks.

Comment: That's the address of the NSNumber object, rather than its contents. It's because you forgot to call -boolValue

Answer (score 4):

To complete Philippe answer, you should make usage of litteral string introduced in **XCode 4.4** with the release of **Apple LLVM Compiler version 4.0**.

Your code will look like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

array[0] = @YES;

//Value is 1
NSLog(@"Value is %d:", [array[0]  boolValue]);
```

Comment: ...and what should be the output?

Comment: %d will format the output to a number so you will see "Value is 1"